# `pnpm add` within a workspace does not add projects from workspace

Tags: monorepo, pnpm

I am working with a very simple monorepo with the following structure:

```
.npmrc
package.json
pnpm-workspaces.yml
packages/
  package-1/
  package-2/
```

When I `cd` into package-1, I am trying to add a reference to package-2 by doing the following:

```sh
pnpm add @myorg/package-2
```

But I get the error `@myorg/package-2 is not in the npm registry, or you have no permission to fetch it.`. I expect that `pnpm add` would detect that I'm inside a workspace and automatically link workspace packages. Am I missing something here?

Here is the relevant information you should need:

- My packages use the `@myorg/[package-name]` convention inside of package.json "name" field.
- The pnpm-workspaces.yml file is as follows:

  ```
  packages:
    - 'packages/**'
  ```
- My .npmrc file is as follows:

  ```
  link-workspace-packages = true
  prefer-workspace-packages = true
  recursive-install = true
  ```

Comment: After making the same mistake: run `pnpm help -w` to quickly check if pnpm was able to load your workspace configuration. If you receive an error, there might be typos.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ugh, I'm leaving this in case anybody else wants to feel embarrassed for themselves.

The `pnpm-workspaces.yml` should be named `pnpm-workspace.yaml` - I'm not sure where I got the other invalid name... but hopefully this helps you waste less time than I did.

Comment: It's because other package managers (npm and yarn) use the word "workspace" differently: they call each package in the monorepo a workspace. Indeed, you must configure the `workspaces` field in `package.json`. Instead, pnpm, lerna and IDEs like VS Code use the word "workspace" for "a group of related projects". In pnpm and lerna, each project is called a package.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of all of that. My problem was that pnpm could not figure out I was inside a workspace because there was not workspace config. This threw me for a loop because I thought I had named the workspace file correctly. I spent way too much time trying to figure that I had a spelling error. My answer is mostly here to be like "hey triple check your spelling you goof".

Comment: I cant beleave I did the same mistake.

Comment: It also helps if you don't call it .pnpm-workspace.yaml like I had

Comment: I did the exact same, and helped resolve the "ERR_PNPM_NO_MATCHING_VERSION_INSIDE_WORKSPACE  In : No matching version found for" error